# Event Listener when a browser finishes updating the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, browser

There is a huge HTML table and JS code that sorts it.
I want to show some loading icon or an overlay when the sorting code is executed.
All works fine, but there is a time gap between end of code and the actual appearance of the updated table.
My guess it that it takes some time until the browser finishes redrawing the page.
I have tried using Observer, but it fires only after the DOM modification, there is still a delay before I can see the actual updated table.
Is there any JS event that happens after the browser finishes drawing the page?

Comment: You can't just call a function at the end of the sort code?

Comment: That is the first thing I tried to do, but it turns out when such a huge DOM update occurs, it takes to the browser some time to actually show the updated elements.  So, using your method, the function is called in the end of the sorting code and 2-5 seconds later you can see the updated table.

Comment: In that case call your function in a timeout: `setTimeout(yourFunction, 0);`. This will allow the UI to update before the function is called. ***However*** if you have an operation running in a page which is taking 5+ seconds to run then that's a big problem. I'd suggest you should look instead to refactor your code, or reduce the amount of data your rendering.

Comment: I was also thinking about a timeout, but it is not the best solution as the time always changes depending on the table length and current CPU & RAM load. Unfortunately the client wants to see all the data at once and the problem is not the sorting code itself.

Comment: What have you tried exactly using MutationObserver?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the trigger to fire off events at the start and end of your processing.

If you're using jQuery it would look something like this:

```
function processTable(){
  $(document).trigger('startProcessing', {
    description: 'Enable Loader'
  });

... //Processing done here

  $(document).trigger('endProcessing', {
    description: 'Disable Loader'
  });
}


jQuery(document).on('startProcessing',enableLoaderFunction);
jQuery(document).on('endProcessing',disableLoaderFunction);
```

This can also be done in just JS by making sure that you use the proper event handler for the browser that is being used.
Here is the documentation for handling without jQuery:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: That is the same as calling a function in the end of the sorting process. Unfortunately, after the endProcess trigger, there is a delay until the table is updated.